# Conditional joint probability with continuous variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ have the joint pdf

$f(x, y) = 2, \quad 0 < x < y < 1 \quad 0, \quad$ otherwise

Find $P(0 < X < 1/2$ | $y = 3/4)$

The solutions say

$\int_0^{1/2} f_{X|Y}(x | y = 3/4)dx$

I know that $f_{X|Y}(x | Y = y) = 2$, but how do I find $f_{X|Y}(x | y = 3/4)$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the figure, which shows the region in which $f(x,y) = 2$ and the particular value $y = 3/4$.  What is the chance that a point on the red line ($y = 3/4$) has value $x<1/2$?
[image]

Comment: I don't understand. I'm not even sure why that figure shows the region $f(x, y) = 2$.

Comment: So I figured out how to do this with an actual pdf chart. Is there a way to convert that pdf I gave in the original question into a chart-form?

Answer (score 0):

$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\displaystyle \int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x} = \dfrac{1}{y}\quad\mathbf 1_{0< x< y< 1}$

That is $X$ (conditioned on $Y=y$) is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0;y)$